# if I get the asymptotic solution of a certain equation involving $ f(x)$ does it mean that the solution exists

Tags: asymptotics, functional-equations

Let's take a complicated functional equation $ f(g(x))=f(1-x)g(x) $.

Let us suppose that by using

a) Analytic method

b) Numerical method

I can prove that for example $ f(x) \sim x $ as $ x\rightarrow \infty $; does it mean that I have proved that a solution for the functional equation exists ?

Let's take another problem: I know the function implicitly $f^{-1}(x)= x+d(x)$;
here $ d(x)$ is an oscillating function smaller than $x$ for example $d(x) = O(\log x) $ then the approximate solution is $f(x)=x$ in case we ignore the inverse of $d(x) $

Have I proven that the function $x+d(x)$ is *invertible*?  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, it's implicitly **given** that $ x \mapsto x + d ( x ) $ is invertible. That's because it's equal to $ f ^ { - 1 } $, which means that you had an injective function $ f $, so you could define its inverse $ f ^ { - 1 } $, and $ x \mapsto x + d ( x ) $ must be invertible with the inverse $ ( f ^ { - 1 } ) ^ { - 1 } = f $. Moreover, if you want the equality $ f ^ { - 1 } ( x ) = x + d ( x ) $ to make sense for **every** $ x $, then the domains of $ f ^ { - 1 } $ and $ d $ must be equal to the codomain of $ f $. In that case, $ f $ would be surjective and hence bijective, which means that $ f ^ { - 1 } $ would be bijective, and hence $ x \mapsto x + d ( x ) $ would be invertible in a stronger sense. The facts that $ d ( x ) = O ( \log x ) $ and $ f ( x ) \sim x $ as $ x \to \infty $ have nothing to do with invertibility of $ x \mapsto x + d ( x ) $ (and also, that kind of reasoning doesn't count as "ignoring the inverse of $ d $"). Take $ d ( x ) $ to be $ \sin x $ and $ \sin ( 2 x ) $ and see why. So that way you can't prove invertibility, but again you don't need to, since invertibility is implicitly given as part of the assumptions.

The answer to your first question is "no", if I get it right. I suppose by "I can prove that $ f ( x ) \sim x $ as $ x \to \infty $" you mean that **if** $ f $ is a function satisfying the given functional equation, then it has that property. Of course this doesn't mean that a solution to the functional equation exists, as for example you can use other methods and get that $ f $ must have further properties which are not compatible with $ f ( x ) \sim x $, which would mean that there is no solution. For a very ugly example, take the functional equation $ f ( x ) = f ( x ) + 1 $, which obviously does not have any solutions. You can prove that **any** function $ f $ satisfying this equation has the property $ f ( x ) \sim x $ as $ x \to \infty $ (or any other property for that matter). You can argue as follows: $ f ( x ) = f ( x ) + 1 $, thus $ 0 = 1 $ by subtracting $ f ( x ) $ from both sides, and then $ 0 = \frac 1 x f ( x ) - 1 $ by multiplying both sides by $ \frac 1 x f ( x ) - 1 $. This shows that $ f ( x ) = x $ for every $ x $, which in turn leads to $ f ( x ) \sim x $ as $ x \to \infty $, while we know that there is no $ f $ satisfying the functional equation.

The fact is that when a functional equation has no solutions, the assumption that $ f $ satisfies it is a false statement, which implies **anything**, including any asymptotic behavior you want. In other words, whatever you want will be vacuously true. For the equation $ f ( x ) = f ( x ) + 1 $ above, I intentionally chose to present an argument which is more of computational nature than logical, to indicate that your path leading to the properties of the possible solutions may fit into the categories of "analytic" or "numerical" as you wanted, while there are no solutions due to another line of thought that you haven't considered yet.